Factor for observed redshift - light dispersion (chromatic aberration) caused by a gravitational lensing
This thought tortured me for a while now, and I can't find if this has been hypothesized/discussed before, and if so, is there a consensus:
Can redshift be to at least some degree a result of a dispersion of light (chromatic aberration) caused by a gravitational lensing?
If my understanding is correct, this would correlate to observed increased redshift rate with increase of distance from observed light source - larger distance generally would allow more occurrences of gravitational lensing due to generally larger amount of mass on/near the path required to reach the observer.
Assumption I make - dispersion (chromatic aberration) caused by a gravitational lensing a)must exist, and b)must be of a similar nature to a dispersion in prism/optical lens - longer wavelength retain original direction better compared to shorter wavelengths, and shorter wavelengths are dispersed at a higher rates, thus observer perceives a red-shifted image.
